# MySQL error with NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run this query in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    userpass VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    phone BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)
```

MySQL returns this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, 
>       userpass VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>       first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>     ' at line 3

I cant figure out what is wrong with the code...

Comment: Thank you it works!!! Do i have to set necessarily a specific size ? i mean for example VARCHAR has a range 0-65535. I thought that (size) was optional.

Comment: No, size is not optional.

Comment: OK thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify size for `VARCHAR` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE users( user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   userpass VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                   phone  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                   PRIMARY KEY(user_id) );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0292a2)**</kbd>

Storing phone number as `BIGINT` is not best idea. Consider normal string instead.